# Java 9 - Can I add the MainClass attribute to module-info.class in the archive?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, java-9

In Java 9, you can create a JAR file with

```
jar --create --file=mlib/com.greetings.jar --main-class=com.greetings.Main -C mods/com.greetings .
```

Which has the side effect of adding the MainClass attribute to the module-info.class file in the .jar file.

Do any of the plugins support this yet, or do I need to invoke the Java 9 'jar' command directly?

Is this the right forum to be asking these questions, or is there a better place?

Cheers, Eric

Comment: Ticket to add feature you want to `maven-jar-plugin` : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-238

Comment: `jar -c -f mlib/com.hello.client.jar --main-class=com/hello/client/HelloWorldClient -C output .`

Answer (score 6):

The 'module main class' is actually an attribute of the module-info.class file. It's called `ModuleMainClass` and set by the Java 9's `jar` command. The current version (3.0.2) of `maven-jar-plugin` only writes the file when you specify the `manifest.mainClass`